# Cumulative unique value count till current row

Tags: sql, oracle

Here my data table:

```
SUBMISSION_DATE     SUBMISSION_ID   USER_ID     USER_NAME
01-MAR-16           8494            20703       Angela
01-MAR-16           30173           36396       Frank
01-MAR-16           22403           53473       Kimberly
01-MAR-16           23965           79722       Michael
02-MAR-16           38740           15758       Rose
02-MAR-16           34928           20703       Angela
02-MAR-16           42769           79722       Michael
02-MAR-16           44364           79722       Michael
03-MAR-16           45440           20703       Angela
03-MAR-16           49050           36396       Frank
03-MAR-16           50273           79722       Michael
04-MAR-16           50344           20703       Angela
04-MAR-16           51360           44065       Lisa
04-MAR-16           54404           53473       Kimberly
04-MAR-16           61533           79722       Michael
05-MAR-16           72852           20703       Angela
05-MAR-16           82439           36396       Frank
05-MAR-16           9006            36396       Frank
05-MAR-16           74546           38289       Patrick
05-MAR-16           76487           62529       Bonnie
06-MAR-16           90404           20703       Angela
```

Now my requirement is to the unique users for that date and including previous date.

Example:

On 1<sup>st</sup> March 2016 there are 4 unique users Angela, Frank, Kimberly and Michael so my unique user count will be 4.

Now for 2<sup>nd</sup> March 2016 there are Rose, Angela, Michael and Michael, since we have 2 unique users Angela (came twice) and Michel (came thrice) the count is will be 2, including current and all previous rows have only two common users.

Now for 3<sup>rd</sup> March 2016 there will be only two common users we get across current and all previous rows.

Same on 4<sup>th</sup> March 2016 we have 2 common values across previous rows.

On 5<sup>th</sup> & 6<sup>th</sup> we have only one which is Angela

So my result will be like below

```
SUBMISSION_DATE     UNIQUE_USER_COUNT
01-Mar-2016         4                   
02-Mar-2016         2                   
03-Mar-2016         2                   
04-Mar-2016         2                   
05-Mar-2016         1                   
06-Mar-2016         1
```

I was trying to achieve that result but now sure how to do counting in such a way using SQL or specific to Oracle and it should not be achieved by PL/SQL.

Comment: From your description it looks like you need *repeated* values, not unique.

Comment: And what should it return if there wouldn't be 'Angela' on '05-MAR-16'? so should it return 0 for both 05-MAR-16 and 06-MAR-16?

Comment: and what should it return in case of missing rows for some date, for example '02-mar-2016'? Should it return 0 for all dates>02-mar-2016?

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions `dense_rank()` and `rank()` to get number of appearances of each user each day and then `group by submission_date` with conditional aggregation:

```
select t.submission_date,
       count(case when t.rnk = t.day then 1 end) unique_user_count
from (
  select t.submission_date,
    dense_rank() over (order by t.submission_date) day,
    rank() over (partition by t.user_id order by t.submission_date) rnk
  from (select distinct submission_date, user_id from tablename) t
) t
group by t.submission_date
order by t.submission_date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e27bb22bf739dd14aeaaad218e23a5f3).
Results:

```
> SUBMISSION_DATE | UNIQUE_USER_COUNT
> :-------------- | ----------------:
> 01-MAR-16       |                 4
> 02-MAR-16       |                 2
> 03-MAR-16       |                 2
> 04-MAR-16       |                 2
> 05-MAR-16       |                 1
> 06-MAR-16       |                 1
```

Comment: Thanks this make sense let me try

Comment: @AtulSinghRathore if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

For each user (assuming identified by `user_id`) compute the number of dates where he appears. For any particular date, users who appear in all dates so far have cumulative sum equal to order of that date:

```sql
with t (submission_date, user_id) as (
select date '2016-03-01', 20703 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-01', 36396 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-01', 53473 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-01', 79722 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-02', 15758 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-02', 20703 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-02', 79722 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-02', 79722 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-03', 20703 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-03', 36396 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-03', 79722 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-04', 20703 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-04', 44065 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-04', 53473 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-04', 79722 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-05', 20703 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-05', 36396 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-05', 36396 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-05', 38289 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-05', 62529 from dual union all
select date '2016-03-06', 20703 from dual
), d (submission_date, user_id) as (
  select distinct submission_date, user_id
  from t
), preprocess (submission_date, user_id, rn, dr) as (
  select submission_date
       , user_id
       , row_number() over (partition by user_id order by submission_date)
       , dense_rank() over (order by submission_date)
  from d order by 1,2
)
select submission_date, count(*)
from preprocess
where dr = rn
group by submission_date
order by submission_date
```

[Db fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=728e1b7a41e36552692d6b8c912023d0)

If the window function equivalent of `multiset intersect` existed, this example would be solvable by almost one-liner :-).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, another solution based on recursive subquery factoring and multiset operators (not for production, because of slow performance):

```sql
with tablename(SUBMISSION_DATE , SUBMISSION_ID, USER_ID, USER_NAME) as (
select to_date('01-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 8494, 20703, 'Angela' from dual union all
select to_date('01-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 30173, 36396, 'Frank' from dual union all
select to_date('01-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 22403, 53473, 'Kimberly' from dual union all
select to_date('01-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 23965, 79722, 'Michael' from dual union all
select to_date('02-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 38740, 15758, 'Rose' from dual union all
select to_date('02-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 34928, 20703, 'Angela' from dual union all
select to_date('02-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 42769, 79722, 'Michael' from dual union all
select to_date('02-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 44364, 79722, 'Michael' from dual union all
select to_date('03-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 45440, 20703, 'Angela' from dual union all
select to_date('03-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 49050, 36396, 'Frank' from dual union all
select to_date('03-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 50273, 79722, 'Michael' from dual union all
select to_date('04-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 50344, 20703, 'Angela' from dual union all
select to_date('04-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 51360, 44065, 'Lisa' from dual union all
select to_date('04-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 54404, 53473, 'Kimberly' from dual union all
select to_date('04-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 61533, 79722, 'Michael' from dual union all
select to_date('05-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 72852, 20703, 'Angela' from dual union all
select to_date('05-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 82439, 36396, 'Frank' from dual union all
select to_date('05-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 9006, 36396, 'Frank' from dual union all
select to_date('05-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 74546, 38289, 'Patrick' from dual union all
select to_date('05-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 76487, 62529, 'Bonnie' from dual union all
select to_date('06-Mar-2016','dd-mon-yyyy'), 90404, 20703, 'Angela' from dual 
)
,agg as (
    select SUBMISSION_DATE
        , cast(collect(distinct USER_NAME) as sys.ku$_vcnt) users
        , row_number()over(order by SUBMISSION_DATE) n
    from tablename
    group by SUBMISSION_DATE
)
,cte(sdate,users) as (
     select SUBMISSION_DATE
        , users
     from agg
     where n=1
     union all
     select SUBMISSION_DATE
        , cte.users multiset intersect agg.users users
     from cte, agg
     where sdate + 1 = SUBMISSION_DATE
)
select
   sdate,
   cardinality(users) cnt,
   users
from cte;
```

Results:

```
SDATE                      CNT USERS
------------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-03-01 00:00:00          4 KU$_VCNT('Angela', 'Frank', 'Kimberly', 'Michael')
2016-03-02 00:00:00          2 KU$_VCNT('Angela', 'Michael')
2016-03-03 00:00:00          2 KU$_VCNT('Angela', 'Michael')
2016-03-04 00:00:00          2 KU$_VCNT('Angela', 'Michael')
2016-03-05 00:00:00          1 KU$_VCNT('Angela')
2016-03-06 00:00:00          1 KU$_VCNT('Angela')
```

Comment: Upvoting since that's the way how I started solving problem at first. I wanted to attach dbfiddle but I failed with `cast(collect ... as sys.ku$_vcnt)` not working on dbfiddle.uk (website fail, empty result or `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got ANYDATA`). I believe your example works on your db but have no clue why it doesn't work on dbfiddle.

Comment: @TomášZáluský DBFIDDLE doesn't support collection types :)

Comment: and VARRAYs too

Comment: it is not feasible as the data I have given is a sample and are subject to vary its not fixed